# AngularJS - clients have separate MongoDB databases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

So I've been stuck with this task for hours and can't seem to find the answer.

My problem is that I have a mean stack application that accepts multiple clients what I want is every client has their own database is it possible ?

**Example**

```
var client_name = Client 1 or Client 2;
```

**Backend**

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + client_name, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log("not connected " + err);
  } else {
    console.log("connected");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since MongoDB is able to to have multiple databases - yes. [MongooseJS connection documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html). This should work for you:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my-database-name');
```

#### With dyanmic database name:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/' + client_name);
```